# How to push the values into array with key name using node.js to construct a json

Tags: json, node.js

I have a node js code with variables:
    var elements = [];
    var subelement1 = {};
    var subelement2 = {};

How to construct the json with the structure as following:

```
{
     "elements":[
     "subelement1" :{},
     "subelement2" :{}  
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine them, set each "*sub*" object to a property of the main:

```
elements.subelement1 = subelement1;
elements.subelement2 = subelement2;
```

Then, you can [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) them with the surrounding object:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({ elements: elements });
```

Though, with named keys, you'll want to use an `Object`.

```
var elements = {};
```

```
{
    "elements": {
        "subelement1": {},
        "subelement2": {}
    }
}
```

While `Array`s can have named properties, they can't be given within a literal.

```
var foo = [];
foo.bar = 'baz';
```

And won't be acknowledged/[counted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) like numeric indexes.

```
console.log(foo.bar);    // "baz"
console.log(foo.length); // 0

foo[0] = 'qux';
console.log(foo.length); // 1
```